# Adding two 2D masked arrays with conflicting masks together?

Tags: numpy

I'll present exactly what I want to do, instead of creating a bare bones question, so I don't lose any of the information I want to convey in the process.

I have two "images" that I want to add together. In the figure below, the left plot shows an uniform circle where yellow represents 1 and elsewhere is 0. In essence, I have a radius that delimits whether a point has current or not.

```
# Create image for an aperture of radius aperture_px/2
mask = xx**2 + yy**2 <= (aperture_px/2)**2 # boolean array
raw = mask.astype(float)
plt.imshow(raw)
```

The second image (right) is a gaussian-like function defined as follows, where I need to only take values outside of that radius.

```
graw = np.exp(-(np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy**2) - aperture_px/2)**2/(2 * s_px.value**2))
ggraw = np.ma.array(graw, mask=mask)
plt.imshow(ggraw)
```

I want to add both arrays, but so far I can't seem to understand how to do so. If I add them directly, the mask from the second array "erases" the values from the first. I can't apply the mask directly to the second array, since it flattens it. It would be ideal if I could just go

```
raw + graw[~mask]
```

and call it a day. Is there a way to correctly mask an array without recurring to MaskedArray? Is there a simple way to add these two images together that does not take me back to just building things in a for loop?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always embarrassing to ask a question and figure out the answer right away. Here's a workaround for what I need to do that does not use masked arrays and therefore doesn't run into the conflicting masks problem:

```
graw = np.where(~mask, graw, 0.)
image = raw + graw
```

Here, I'm using np.where to replace the values inside the circle (as defined by the mask) to 0. Then, I can just add both arrays normally. I guess this is the correct way to apply a mask to a nD array.

Comment: While the `np.ma` array subclass has been around for a long time, I don't think it's heavily used.  `pandas` has taken over its uses when dealing with missing data in time series. And as you found it has only rule for 'reconciling' conflicting masks.

Comment: For all binary `ufunc` (`np.add` etc), the result `mask` is `np.logical_or(a,.mask, b.mask)`.  If either is masked, the result element is also masked.  That makes sense if masking primarily marks missing or invalid values.